# GeneXus 16 .NET Web - Consume SOAP service via External Object with Basic Authentication

Tags: genexus

I have Consumer (GX16 U5 .NET) and a Provider (GX15 U6 Java) that are talking via SOAP.  The Provider expects the "Authorization" HTTP Header with Basic Authentication but my Consumer is apparently not including the Header (as seen from TCPTrace) even though I have set the Authentication to Yes, Auth Method to Basic, and provided the creds.

I am using an External Object created from the WSDL inspector to consume the service, and I set the Location variable accordingly.

Is there something special on the .NET side (or even in IIS) I need to do to include the Header?

I have a second Consumer from a third KB (GX16 U5 Java) that consumes this SAME EXACT Provider just fine - the HTTP Header is included.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The reason why .NET does not include the Authorization header in the first attempt is because it is not Preemptive.

The opposite behavior, in some cases is considered less secure, which is to send the credentials on the first request. (This is called Preemptive Authentication)

If the provider returns 401 error code after the first attempt .NET will execute a second attempt that will include the Authorization header with the credentials. 
If the provider returns a different code, there will not be a second attempt. We believe this is your case.

To sump up:
When the service is invoked, the following is done:
- The request will be made without sending the credentials.
- The server responds an error 401 with a header of the type: Authorization: Basic dXNlcjpwYXNz.
- A second request is executed, now with the credentials. The Authorization Header goes with Authorization : Basic dXNlcjpwYXNz
- The server authenticates the user and responds with Http code 200.

Workaround:
In order to send the Authorization header you may need to use httpclient by including a specific procedure for every service that matters, and replacing your ExternalObject.

Below you will find the example:

Event 'TestHTTP'

&HTTPClient.Host = "localhost"

&HTTPClient.Port = 8089

&HTTPClient.BaseURL = "/version8JavaEnvironment/servlet/"

&HTTPClient.AddHeader("Content-type", "text/xml;charset=utf-8")

&HTTPClient.AddHeader("SOAPAction", "version8action/ASERVICEPROVIDER.Execute")

&HTTPClient.AddHeader("Authorization", "ppppppppppppppppppppppppp")

&XMLWriter.OpenRequest(&HTTPClient)

&XMLWriter.WriteStartDocument("utf-8", 0)

&XMLWriter.WriteStartElement("SOAP-ENVEnvelope")

&XMLWriter.WriteAttribute("xmlnsSOAP-ENV",http//schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")

&XMLWriter.WriteAttribute("xmlnsxsd", "http//www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema")

&XMLWriter.WriteAttribute("xmlnsSOAP-ENC",http//schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/")

&XMLWriter.WriteAttribute("xmlnsxsi", "http//www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")

&XMLWriter.WriteStartElement("SOAP-ENVBody")

&XMLWriter.WriteElement("ServiceProvider.Execute", "")

&XMLWriter.WriteAttribute("xmlns", "version8")

&XMLWriter.WriteEndElement()

&XMLWriter.Close()

&HTTPClient.Execute("POST", "targetResourceName")

&longvarchar = &HTTPClient.ToString()

Endevent

Comment: In my case I never saw a 'second attempt' with the HTTP Header being sent so I am not sure this is my case.  In the end I still think the .NET code should send the Authorization HTTP Header if I tell it to when I configure the Location variable.

I decided to switch over to REST on both sides and have this working with the HTTP Client.